# wifiSetEnabled(true) occasionally not working

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I'm making my first app so i'm not really an expert. BTW in my app I've create this Service which should enable or disable wi-fi according to a boolean value that I'm passing to the Service through the pending intent that I use to start (the Service, I'm using an AlarmManager to do this).

Now, everything works fine in most cases, but sometimes my wifi won't turn on, and I'm sure that the Service is started because it successfully complete other works it's supposed to do. 
I first thought it was permission's fault, but you can see all the permission i'm using in the manifest below.

Looking around here in StackOverflow someone suggested to add UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS permission but I don't think this is the solution because as I already said: SOMETIMES IT WORKS.

Important: I notice that it can't enable it usually when the wifi is turned off from a while, like few hours. 
This is the snippet from the Service: (TSManagerHelper is the class with the pending intent and the values)

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    boolean op2;

    WifiManager wifiManager=(WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

    Bundle bundle;

    if(intent!=null) {
        bundle = intent.getExtras();
        op2 = bundle.getBoolean(TSManagerHelper.OPTION2);

        //WI-FI
        if(op2 != wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            if(op2)
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            else
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }
```

This are Manifest's permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Any idea? I repeat that I'm really unexperted, thanks to whoever will  help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too. And I solved it when I run the same code with airplane mode turned OFF. So if you could check the whether airplane mode is turned on or not before enabling the Wi-Fi